# Missing print-out for MPI root process, after its handling data reading alone

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90, openmpi

I'm writing a project that firstly designates the root process to read a large data file and do some calculations, and secondly broadcast the calculated results to all other processes.  Here is my code: (1) it reads random numbers from a txt file with `nsample=30000` (2) generate `dens_ent` matrix by some rule (3) broadcast to other processes. Btw, I'm using OpenMPI with gfortran.

```
IF (myid==0) THEN
  OPEN(UNIT=8,FILE='rnseed_ent20.txt')
  DO i=1,n_sample
    DO j=1,3
      READ(8,*) rn(i,j)
    END DO
  END DO
  CLOSE(8)
 END IF

 dens_ent=0.0d0
 DO i=1,n_sample
 IF (myid==0) THEN
  !Random draws of productivity and savings
  rn_zb=MC_JOINT_SAMPLE((/-0.1d0,mu_b0/),var,rn(i,1:2))
  iz=minloc(abs(log(zgrid)-rn_zb(1)),dim=1)
  ib=minloc(abs(log(bgrid(1:nb/2))-rn_zb(2)),dim=1) !Find the closest saving grid
  CALL SUB2IND(j,(/nb,nm,nk,nxi,nz/),(/ib,1,1,1,iz/))
  DO iixi=1,nxi
    DO iiz=1,nz
      CALL SUB2IND(jj,(/nb,nm,nk,nxi,nz/),(/policybmk_2_statebmk_index(j,:),iixi,iiz/))
      dens_ent(jj)=dens_ent(jj)+1.0d0/real(nxi)*markovian(iz,iiz)*merge(1.0d0,0.0d0,vent(j) .GE. -bgrid(ib)+ce)
      !Density only recorded if the value of entry is greater than b0+ce
    END DO
  END DO
END IF
END DO

 PRINT *, 'dingdongdingdong',myid


 IF (myid==0) dens_ent=dens_ent/real(n_sample)*Mpo
 IF (myid==0) PRINT *, 'sum_density by joint normal distribution',sum(dens_ent)

 PRINT *, 'BLBLALALALALALA',myid

 CALL MPI_BCAST(dens_ent,N,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

Problem arises: 
    (1) `IF (myid==0) PRINT *, 'sum_density by joint normal distribution',sum(dens_ent)` seems not executed, as there is no print out.
    (2) I then verify this by adding `PRINT *, 'BLBLALALALALALA',myid` etc  messages. Again no print out for root process `myid=0`. 
    It seems like root process is not working? How can this be true? I'm quite confused. Is it because I'm not using `MPI_BARRIER` before `PRINT *, 'dingdongdingdong',myid`?

Comment: You are awfully close to skirting the rules of this site. There are specific rules against: "Here's my code, please debug it for me." You also do not show how `myid` is calculated. That said, I'd suggest using a `unit` of 10 or more for file-i/o (normally `STD_OUT` should be unit 6, but you never know), and also check all the `ierr` status values after each MPI call.

Comment: Plus, you are not very forthcoming on the output that you get. Do the non-root processes print "BLABLABLA"? Does the root process print "dingdong"? How many processes are you running?

Comment: In addition to previous comments, do you mean `MPI_BCAST` rather than `MPI_BARRIER`?

Comment: @chw21, checking the error code of MPI calls not related to file I/O is pointless. Unless the error handler is explicitly set to `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN`, MPI calls do not return. Instead, the program gets aborted immediately. `MPI_ERRORS_RETURN` is the default error handler for MPI file objects only.

Comment: @chw21 Sorry that my post looks like a debug-for-me one. To your second question, anything should be printed on root process is not printed. Could you explain why there's such a rule of thumb about `unit` numbering for file-i/o? Thanks!

Comment: @Harald Sorry for the confusion.  I'm wondering if it's because I'm not using `MPI_BARRIER` before `PRINT *, 'dingdongdingdong',myid`  such that all other processes will wait for the root process to finish all data readings and calculations.

Comment: @WoodpeckerWang instead of editing *(solved)* in the title, please accept the answer that helped you, id you solved it yourself, post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Do not put any (solved) in the title. Accept an answer or write your own instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you miss the following statement just at the very beginning of your code?

```
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK (MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
IF (ierr /= MPI_SUCCESS) THEN
    STOP "MPI_COMM_RANK failed!"
END IF
```

The `MPI_COMM_RANK` returns into `myid` (if succeeds) the identifier of the process within the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator (i.e a value within 0 and NP, where NP is the total number of MPI ranks).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contributions from @cw21 @Harald and @Hristo Iliev.
        The failure lies in `unit` numbering. One reference says:

```
unit number : This must be present and takes any integer type. Note    this ‘number’ identifies the
file and must be unique so if you have more than one file open then you must specify a different
unit number for each file. Avoid using 0,5 or 6 as these UNITs are typically picked to be used by
Fortran as follows.
– Standard Error = 0 : Used to print error messages to the screen.
– Standard In = 5 : Used to read in data from the keyboard.
– Standard Out = 6 : Used to print general output to the screen.
```

So I changed all numbering `i` into `1i`, not working; then changed into `10i`. It starts to work. Mysteriously, as correctly pointed out by @Hristo Iliev, as long as the numbering is not `0,5,6`, the code should behave properly. I cannot explain to myself why `1i` not working. But anyhow, the root process is now printing out results.